# It seems jvm param will not be accepted by quarkus

Tags: quarkus

I am running a fat jar packaged by  quarkus with jvm param -Duser.language=en
but it seems , not accepted by quarkus. Any suggestion / hints for solving this problem?

```
java -jar MyApp.jar -Duser.language=en
    __  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______
     --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
     -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
    --\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/
    2021-03-11 09:57:38,910 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.cor.CamelBootstrapRecorder] (main) bootstrap runtime: org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMainRuntime
    2021-03-11 09:57:38,914 INFO  [org.apa.cam.qua.mai.CamelMainRuntime] (main) Starting camel-quarkus with args: [-Duser.language=en]
    Unknown option: -Duser.language=en
```

Comment: Try `java -Duser.language=en -jar MyApp.jar`. Arguments _before_ `-jar` are handled by the JVM, while arguments _after_ `-jar` are supposed to be handled by the application.

Comment: You are the hero ! thanks!

Comment: Great to hear that. I'll make it a "real" answer then!

Answer (score 2):

Try `java -Duser.language=en -jar MyApp.jar`.

Arguments *before* `-jar` are handled by the JVM, while arguments *after* `-jar` are supposed to be handled by the application.